# Generate multiple executables with 1 different variable value MVS C#

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, code-generation, executable

I'm making a program which contains a string key variable which should be different for each executable that I generate.
I have a list of 50 string key values which I want to use for 50 .exes.

What's the best way to do this?
I'm using C# in Visual Studio.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

```
    static string key = "X";
```

This line of code is in my project. Now I want to generate 50 exes where I replace the X with another value.

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking.  Do you want to make 50 copies of the same executable (with different names), or do you want to run the same executable 50 times with different input?  Or something else entirely?

Comment: I want 50 executables in which one variable a string has a different value for each executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to have a command-line argument which fills your key-variable, so you'd only have 1 executable and 50 links to it.

Using 50 .exe-files you could use pre-processor conditions to set different values for `key` and a batch-file which calls `csc.exe` with 50 different variables.

But that all sounds strange. May you have some base-problem, which could have simpler solutions? Think of the [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If its so, consider posting a new question.